# copy startdate and enddate to other line

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

And I want to copy the startDate and Enddate copiing to the other line,

I have this:

```
GetDates(Bom : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDateItem : Date;VAR EndDateItem : Date;RegelkortingItem : Decimal)

IF GET(Bom."Parent Item No.",Bom."Line No.") THEN BEGIN
  StartDateItem :=StartDate2;
  EndDateItem := EndDate2;
  RegelkortingItem := Regelkorting;
END;

SetDates(Bom : Record "BOM Component";VAR StartDateItem : Date;VAR EndDateItem : Date;RegelkortingItem : Decimal)
"Parent Item No." := Bom."Parent Item No.";
"Line No." := Bom."Line No.";
StartDate2 := StartDateItem;
EndDate2 := EndDateItem;
Regelkorting := RegelkortingItem;

IF NOT MODIFY THEN 
  INSERT;
```

And this is a image

[image]

The black marker line - there the same date has to be copiied

Thank you

And this is the onvalidate:

```
BeginDate - OnValidate()
SetDates(Rec, StartDate2, EndDate2, Regelkorting);
```

So I try this:

```
Rec.SETRANGE(StartDate2,StartDate2);
IF StartDate2 <> StartDate2  THEN
//IF (Rec.COUNT > 1) THEN //AND  (FORMAT(Rec.StartDate2) = FORMAT(Rec.StartDate2)))  THEN
ERROR('The dates has to be the same!! ');
//END;
```

So the dates has to be the same.

I have it now like this:

```
IF StartDate2 <> BOMB.StartDate2  THEN
//IF (Rec.COUNT > 1) THEN //AND  (FORMAT(Rec.StartDate2) = FORMAT(Rec.StartDate2)))  THEN
ERROR('The dates has to be the same!! ');
```

But then If I just put one startdate, then the error message is already showing

ok, I have the complete code now like this:

```
SetDates(Rec, StartDate2, EndDate2, Regelkorting);
//StartDateInsert := Rec.StartDate2;
BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2,StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN; 
IF StartDate2 <> BOMB.StartDate2 
THEN ERROR('The dates has to be the same!! ');
```

But nothing happens

See image. After the last line, it is ending debug. and nothing happens:
[image]

For example I want to compare dates: like this:

[image]

Oke, this works. But only on  the first record

```
SetDates(Rec, StartDate2, EndDate2, Regelkorting);
BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2,StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
IF BOMB.StartDate2 > BOMB.EndDate2 THEN BEGIN
ERROR('startdatum kan niet groter zijn dan einddatum');
END;
END
```

Comment: `StartDate2` and `EndDate2` are fields of `BOM` table?

Comment: yes they are ok

Comment: sorry but this question is very chaotic :( Creating Field with Field Name like a Variable Name is not recommended (StartDate2 for example). Using Non-English Variable names is not recommended...

Comment: Put the values of dates in Watch1 of debugger because not seen. and What is your error now??

Answer (score 0):

Firt check when you invoke `SetDates()` function `StartDate2` and `EndDate2` have a correct values. Perhaps here is the error.

**You code is this:**

```
BeginDate - OnValidate()
SetDates(Rec, StartDate2, EndDate2, Regelkorting);
```

Here you pass a `Rec`, `StartDate2` and `EndDate2` They have values of `Rec` and not the correct values.

**Try to change for this code:**

```
BeginDate - OnValidate()
SetDates(Rec, StartDateItem, EndDateItem, Regelkorting);
```

Comment: The last code That's wrong, `rec.SETRANGE(StartDate2, StartDate2)` you filter `rec` with the same value of `rec`, Create a variable of `rec` like recBomTable, BOM. and filter this variable.

Comment: Try this: `BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2, StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN;
IF StartDate2 <> BOMB.StartDate2  THEN
ERROR('The dates has to be the same!! ');`

Comment: I think the record no exist. try this to check. BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2, StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
  IF StartDate2 <> BOMB.StartDate2  THEN
    ERROR('The dates has to be the same!! ');
END ELSE
  ERROR('There is no record with StartDate2 %1', FORMAT(StartDate2));

Comment: Hi, I triied that. But no message will popup

Comment: Hi, think about this, you filter BOM table by date, for example 01/01/2016, you get a record by this date then you compare if this dates are diferent. These date are always going to be the same. example BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2, 01012016D); after FINDFIRST the value for BOMB.StartDate2 is the same filter value, in this example 01/01/2016 (01012016D).

Comment: Hi. Oke, But is the placement: BeginDate-onvalidate not the correct place to define it?

Comment: I update the post. But sorry. What is wrong with it? I added a image. I see that it is of BOMB. SO I compare this values

Comment: Hi, I'm really confused. I do not understand you're trying to do. I recommend you remove this post. And create a new post with a better description.

Comment: Yes, ok. I understand that. I will make a new post. Thank you